# How to update tables using generated set functions in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Hiya, could someone tell me how to use those automatic set functions?

I have a column called "deleted". When a user clicks a link, it goes to a delete action. The delete action previously deleted a row in the db. Now I just want it to set the deleted field value of that row to 1. Symfony has created a function called setDelete(), but I don't know how to use it. I am trying this:

```
$consultant = Doctrine_Core::getTable('consultant')->find(array($request->getParameter('id')));
$consultant->setDeleted('1');
```

I'm not getting any errors, but it's still not updating the table.

Comment: Is this in admin generator or in your own custom `delete` action?

Comment: I don't know what admin generator is!!  It's in the action, the default executeDelete function.

Comment: No matter - see you found the answer below :-) although for info, see http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12 for what admin generator is :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to execute `$consultant->save();` after the set.

By the way, since symfony 1.4.3 you can call `ConsultantTable::getInstance()` instead of `Doctrine_Core::getTable('consultant')` which allows your IDE to autocomplete the methods in the model.

Comment: That's great, thank you.  What does the save() function actually do?  Also, I used getInstance but autocomplete isn't working for my model's methods.

Comment: It applies the changes made to this object into the database. Have a look at the API to see what happens exactly: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and Symfony 1.4.12.  I've been looking for a good auto-complete solution for models like this.  The problem is the methods I care about are usually in the <Model> class, NOT the <Model>Table class and even with 1.4.12, the built-in methods like find() or findOneBy*() in the table classes don't seem to properly declare their return types.  For example, even after calling a SomethingTable::getInstance()->find($id) I can't use method or property lookups on that result, which should be of type object Something.  Any way around this?

Comment: @jweible jep, in netbeans its easy to handle this… try `$foo = ModelNameTable::getInstance()->find(1); /* @var $foo ModelName */` :)